# Django-apache2 exited with code 0 when I write docker-compose up

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I created Dockerfile and docker-compose but gives me this error django-apache2 exited with code 0 when I write `docker-compose up`

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install python3.8
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt -y install apache2
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN  apt-get -y install python3-dev
RUN apt-get -y install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
COPY ./apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN mkdir /var/www/api/
COPY ./project/. /var/www/api/
WORKDIR /project/
```

Docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
 django-apache2:
  container_name: "django-apache2"
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8005:80"
```

Comment: add this to your Dockerfile `CMD [“apache2ctl”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]` or `CMD [“apache2”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”] or `CMD [“apache”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to understand that a Docker container runs a single command. The container will be running as long as that process the command started is running. Once the process is completed and exits then the container will stop.

With that understanding, we can make an assumption of what is happening in your case. When you start your service there is no command. At this point, the Docker container is stopped because the process exited (with status 0).

So you need to add command that keeps running on your docker.

Check this link for more information [Here](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/).

Answer (score 0):

Your container lacks something to run. You need to add a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` instruction to your Dockerfile.

That's why you see such message, **which is not an error**. The message is telling you that your container `django-apache2` finished correctly (exit status 0), and this is because you are running the base image `ubuntu` which doesn't execute anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is due to www-data apache2 user. If you install python packages from Dockerfile they will be installed for superuser and www-data apache user can not access those packages.
I tried creating a new venv using pip and the same problem happens. Packages installed from superuser in a python virtual environment are not installed inside venv folder.
I created a new repository in [github](https://github.com/JoseManuelVargas/django-docker-apache2) explaining a different approach using miniconda3 as the python packages manager and using sudo -u in order to run commands as a different user.
I am trying to solve this using pip. Changes will be posted in the repository.

I hope this can be useful to you.

Comment: you should provide more details of what can be done now, than ensuring that you will provide the changes in future.